# how to obtain a selected part of a dictionary of dictionaries from Alphavantage

Tags: python, dictionary

I got the next endpoint from Alphavantage, but i would like to use the RSI number, for a list of stocks. ¿How can i get just the RSI?
I'll appreciate your answers

```
{

'Meta Data': {'1: Symbol': 'ABMD',
  '2: Indicator': 'Relative Strength Index (RSI)',
  '3: Last Refreshed': '2021-10-13',
  '4: Interval': 'weekly',
  '5: Time Period': 10,
  '6: Series Type': 'open',
  '7: Time Zone': 'US/Eastern Time'},
 'Technical Analysis: RSI': {'2021-10-13': {'RSI': '50.5159'},
  '2021-10-08': {'RSI': '44.3446'},
  '2021-10-01': {'RSI': '55.6364'},
  '2021-09-24': {'RSI': '58.2600'},
  '2021-09-17': {'RSI': '63.0876'},
  '2021-09-10': {'RSI': '68.3045'},
  '2021-09-03': {'RSI': '65.3299'},
  '2021-08-27': {'RSI': '61.9752'},
  '2021-08-20': {'RSI': '52.7723'},
  '2021-08-13': {'RSI': '64.7634'},
```

Comment: are you trying to get a specific key from the dictionary?

Comment: There is many `RSI` - use `for`-loop to get all

Comment: `data['Technical Analysis: RSI']['2021-10-13']['RSI']` for first `RSI`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

For first `RSI`

```py
data['Technical Analysis: RSI']['2021-10-13']['RSI']
```

and the same way you can get for other dates.

---

For all `RSI` you can use `for`-loop with `.values()` or `.items()`

```py
for date, values in data['Technical Analysis: RSI'].items():
    print(date, values['RSI'])
```

---

```py
data = {
    'Meta Data': {
        '1: Symbol': 'ABMD',
        '2: Indicator': 'Relative Strength Index (RSI)',
        '3: Last Refreshed': '2021-10-13',
        '4: Interval': 'weekly',
        '5: Time Period': 10,
        '6: Series Type': 'open',
        '7: Time Zone': 'US/Eastern Time'
    },
    'Technical Analysis: RSI': {
        '2021-10-13': {'RSI': '50.5159'},
        '2021-10-08': {'RSI': '44.3446'},
        '2021-10-01': {'RSI': '55.6364'},
        '2021-09-24': {'RSI': '58.2600'},
        '2021-09-17': {'RSI': '63.0876'},
        '2021-09-10': {'RSI': '68.3045'},
        '2021-09-03': {'RSI': '65.3299'},
        '2021-08-27': {'RSI': '61.9752'},
        '2021-08-20': {'RSI': '52.7723'},
        '2021-08-13': {'RSI': '64.7634'},
    }
}

print('First:', data['Technical Analysis: RSI']['2021-10-13']['RSI'])

print('--- all ---')
for date, values in data['Technical Analysis: RSI'].items():
    print(date, '|', values['RSI'])
```

Result:

```
First: 50.5159
--- all ---
2021-10-13 | 50.5159
2021-10-08 | 44.3446
2021-10-01 | 55.6364
2021-09-24 | 58.2600
2021-09-17 | 63.0876
2021-09-10 | 68.3045
2021-09-03 | 65.3299
2021-08-27 | 61.9752
2021-08-20 | 52.7723
2021-08-13 | 64.7634
```